Duty cycle of UCC28950
The UCC28950 IC is a phase shift full bridge IC.
The link for the document: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf
OUTA, OUTB, OUTC, OUTD outputs control the full bridge MOSFETs on the transformer side.
I examined how the duty cycle of these outputs is set.
There is a duty cycle calculation for burst mode in the datasheet, but this is valid for an energy saving mode.
I could not see any calculation for steady state duty cycle, but I saw the following statement in the datasheet, it says “Connecting an external resistor RT between the RT pin and VREF pins sets the fixed frequency operation and configures the controller as a master providing synchronization output pulses at SYNC pin with 0.5 duty cycle and frequency equal to the internal oscillator.”
So based on this statement, I can arrange the frequency by changing RT and 0.5 fixed duty is for SYNC pin.
Since I didn’t see any duty cycle calculation or statement for outputs, should I assume 0.5 fixed duty as in the case of SYNC pin?

I've rolled this question back to how it was when I made my answer.

Mhan, if the question is answered, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.


I could not see any calculation for steady state duty cycle

There isn't one; duty cycle for the main outputs can vary from nearly zero percent to nearly 100%.

Should I assume 0.5 fixed duty as in the case of SYNC pin ?

That would be wrong.
Duty cycle increases until the output condition is met i.e. \$V_{SENSE}\$ (blue boxes) acquires the right level so that the error amplifier (red box) stabilizes its output on the \$COMP\$ pin. At this point, the duty cycle remains at a value normally around 40% to 80% but, the actual value is wholly determined by your circuit components and power supply voltages.

Image from data sheet linked in OP's question.
The chip is not some kind of fixed duty cycle output generator based on some input voltage; it has this functionality internally but, it also has an error amplifier that takes overall control via an outer feedback loop.

The UCC28950 600W Phase Shifted Full Bridge Design Review/Application Report linked on the TI UCC28950 Technical documentation has an equation for DTYP in the 4 Transformer Calculations (T1) section:



Where how to find DTYP is what I think the question was looking for.
The application report also has guidance on:

DMAX for selecting the transformer turns.
Resistor RTMIN programs the minimum duty cycle on time (tMIN) that the UCC28950/1 (Pin 9) can demand before
entering burst mode.


I saw this calculation, actually I mean how can I set steady duty cycle of outputs (A,B,C,D) on the controller ? in other words, how will I set 0.66 duty on the controller ? @Chester Gillon

The 0.66 is the transformer side duty cyle, in order to get 0.66 duty on transformer we need to arrange the duty, frequency etc. of individual outputs (such as A,B,C,D ). That is why I asked how to set these outputs on the controller for the calculated duty. @Chester Gillon

@Mhan As the answer from Andy says The chip is not some kind of fixed duty cycle output generator based on some input voltage. Since this question already has two answers, suggest you ask a new question about how to get a UCC28950 to output a fixed duty cycle (not sure that is possible).
